# Is there a way to serve a different html file rather than a css file?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I know you can use IE conditional statements to serve CSS files, but is it possible to do the same to html. 
For example, when you go to a website, and it recognizes you are using IE 7, so it serves you a different html file

Comment: This is usually done using a server side language. Why do you need to do that though?

Comment: IE conditional comments are **HTML comments**, not CSS comments. In other words: you can restructure your whole HTML for MSIE. Go crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the HTML is called for first, you'll need to do this server-side. Using PHP, you'll need `if($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] === 'MSIE 7'){ //then... }`